# Excel * symbol in a text string

Tags: string, excel, operators

Does the ' * ' symbol in a text string mean that there can be any characters in the string in the place of ' * '? For some reason it doesn't work in the following code:

```
=COUNTIF(Workbook1!I2:I5000;"2012.01*")
```

Is there an alternative way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are matching ***strings*** then this is fine
`=COUNTIF(Workbook1!I2:I5000;"2012.01*")`

If you are matching against **numbers** then your formula above wont work try this instead
`=COUNTIF(Workbook1!I2:I5000,">=2012.01")`

To match only numbers starting with 2012.01 And less than 2012

in xl07 and onwards
`=COUNTIFS(Workbook1!I2:I5000,">=2012.01",Workbook1!I2:I5000,"<2012.02")`

all versions including xl03
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Workbook1!I2:I5000>=2012.01),--(Workbook1!I2:I5000<2012.02))`

Comment: If you use ">=2012.01" won't that also count future months like 2012.02 etc? [I assume these are dates?]

Comment: @barryhoudini I think you are correct - I (and perhaps Artiso) were thinking of a limited case for numbers starting with 2012.01. I will update for clarity

Comment: Yes, you were correct about the limited cases, however, for some reason the "<2012.02" criteria gives me "0".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the COUNTIF() function can take wildcards. Your problem seems to be that the syntax of your formula is incorrect.

```
=COUNTIF(I2:I5000,"2012.01*")
```